# Updating Database From Static File JSON Feed

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I have a PHP script pulling a JSON file that is static and updates every 10 seconds. It has details about some events that happen and it just adds to the top of the JSON file. I then insert them into a MySQL database.

Because I have to pull every event every time I pull the file, I will only be inserting new events. The easy way would be to search for the event in the database (primary keys are *not* the same), but I am talking about ~4000 events every day, and I do not want that many queries just to see if it exists.

I am aware of `INSERT IGNORE`, but it looks like it only uses `PRIMARY_KEY` to do this.

What can I do (preferably easily) to prevent duplicates on two keys?

Example:

I have a table `events` with the following columns:

- ID (irrelevant, really)
- event_id (that I need to store from the source)
- action_id (many action_ids belong to one event_id)
- timestamp
- whatever...

And my data is my JSON comes out on the first pull like this:

```
event_id|action_id|...
   1    |   1
   1    |   2
   1    |   3
   2    |   1
   2    |   2
   2    |   3
```

Then the next pull is this:

```
event_id|action_id|...
   1    |   1
   1    |   2
   1    |   3
   1**  |   4**
   1**  |   5**
   2    |   1
   2    |   2
   2    |   3
   2**  |   4**
```

I *only* want the rows marked with asterisks to be inserted, and the others to be ignored. Remember, `primary_key` column `id` is completely in this table, and I just use it for ubiquity.

What command can I use to "INSERT" every event I pull, but ONLY adding those that aren't duplicated by way of the two columns `event_id` and `action_id`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a unique index of both columns.

```
CREATE 
    UNIQUE INDEX event_action
    ON tablename (event_id, action_id)
```